# Vim opens some files in readonly mode by default even when use sudo

Tags: vim, sudo

I have weird issue with vim - for some files it doesn't color the syntax and opens it readonly mode by default, even if I use sudo. chmod for this file are 664, I am also owner of this file, so normally i shouldn't.

I have no `set ro` in my vimrc.

I noticed also that it often happens after removing .swp for this file - unfortunately, after this, this particular file is every time opened in readonly mode. One idea is - maybe is this some kind of spf13 cache?

For other files the behavior is correct.

Anyone knows this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found solution - it was more trivial than I expected.

I read the vim messages more carefully and I saw at the end:

```
if you did this already, delete the swap file `~/.vimswap/urls.py.swp`
```

So i did small investigation and i found `.vimviews` inside my /home directory. I just removed it's content and ...it works!

Comment: FYI for neovim it is ~/.local/share/nvim/swap/

Answer (score 0):

Probably spf13. There are WAY too many problems caused by spf13 in my opinion. Try doing `:verbose set readonly?` when you see the problem, to see where it happened from. My guess:

1. I think I remember spf13 having some kind of automatic session management built in, this would restore 'readonly' on a file if it had ever been set on that file.
2. It is quite possible (a fairly common solution) that if spf13 detects an existing swap file, it will automatically open the file in readonly mode, triggering (1).
3. It is also quite possible that some autocmd or another related to (2) sets an empty filetype or syntax, which would likewise be remembered by (1).

If this is the case, you can probably find the session file causing the issue (using that `:verbose set readonly?` command) and delete it.

Also consider, whether you really need all of spf13, or if you could achieve your desired configuration easier by installing plugins and configuring Vim yourself.